# Pass a buildType from android app/library module to java only gradle module

Tags: android, gradle

Gradle `Module A` is an **android** module which defines several custom build types

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEV', 'true'
    }
    internal {
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'INTERNAL', 'true'
    }
    external {
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'EXTERNAL', 'true'
    }
    release {
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'RELEASE', 'true'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation project(":module-b")
}
```

Gradle `Module B` is a **kotlin/java only** module:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.lint'

dependencies {
}
```

Module A depends on module B:

```
// Module A build.gradle
dependencies {
  implementation project(":module-b")
}
```

In `Module B` sources I need to know how exactly is it consumed by `Module A`, what is the current `buildType` of `Module A`: is it 'debug', 'internal', 'external' or 'release'?

Ideally I'd like to have `BuildConfig.java` in `Module B` similar to one provided by an Android Gradle Plugin, but if this is not possible I'd like to have at least *some* way of figuring out the build type in non-android modules.

**EDIT** Another example to put this into perspective: let's say there's one 'app' module and 10 java-only modules. When I execute 'app:assembleExternal' task, then in all 10 java-only modules I want to know that it is "external" build type being built.

Comment: Is there any reason why the module needs to be kotlin/java only?

Comment: There's a few good answers to this on [how to use BuildConfig in an android-library with a flag that gets set in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365928), some of them might apply to a java library module.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a problem with android-library, but I am interested if this could be done in kotlin/java only. A lot of modules do not need android gradle plugin applied to them, this should also considerably speed up the build of a multi-module project.

Comment: Looks like a chicken or egg problem. Why not create a another gradle project which just contains the buildconfig stuff and have both modules `A` and `B` depend on that one?

Comment: Let's say there's one 'app' module and 10 java-only modules. When I execute 'assembleExternal', then in all 10 java-only modules I want to know that it is "external" build type being built. Your suggestion wouldn't solve this, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is by implementing something that inspects the Gradle taskGraph  using `gradle.taskGrpah.whenReady` inside `Module B` and checking if `:module-a:assembleDebug` is part of it, then setting a parameter with value `DEBUG` which can then be picked up by a Gradle Plugin such as `com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig` which will then create the `BuildConfig.java` that gets compiled into the `Module B` output artifact.

It's possible to do it without using android-library plugin, I honestly find it annoying to implement. The annoying part is that the variant is decided or resolved somewhere that is, in my opinion, not easily reachable by code.

Comment: Thanks I guess this will do, I didn't know about that buildconfig plugin, it will help here and `whenReady` is a nice way to hook it once. I will try this soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
api project(":module-b")
```