# How I can access the settings I provided via build config in my code?

Tags: java, android, gradle

As seen in oficial android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) I can use build variants and build my application via different settings.

Therefore, I made my own variants:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"local.example.com"]
            debuggable true
        }

        /**
         * The `initWith` property allows you to copy configurations from other build types,
         * then configure only the settings you want to change. This one copies the debug build
         * type, and then changes the manifest placeholder and application ID.
         */
        staging {
            initWith debug
            manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"staging.example.com"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".debugStaging"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a class where I load all the settings:

```
class ApiUtils {

   public function getApiUrl(String path){
      // I want to populate it with appropriate url from build config
      String url="";
      return url+path;
   }
}
```

How I can populate the `url` variable with the value from `hostName` as provided in `manifestPlaceholders`?

Comment: Don't you have a BuildConfig class that was generated? You can access the values through there. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365928/gradle-how-to-use-buildconfig-in-an-android-library-with-a-flag-that-gets-set or this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips

Comment: Actually I have zero idea what are you talking about. you can offer me a demo as an answer.

Comment: literally type `BuildConfig.` and see if your variable shows up

Comment: Yeah as mentioned, `manifestPlaceholders` is to inject values into AndroidManifest, if you want to use your values from build scripts in code, you need to use BuildConfig, so something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796601/3225458) basically